# Remove variables with repeated occurences in 2 levels

Tags: r, variables, count, dataframe, levels

I am trying to do an automated filtration to get rid of variables that are not useful. I was processing my data in a command that removes any value that get repeated more than "x" times in my table using this command

```
df <- df[, which(apply(df, 2, function(col) !any(table(col) > x)))]
```

I am trying now to apply the same thing but for 2 levels, here's what my data looks like

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 0, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), V2 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 7, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4, 5, 2), V3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), level = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "level"), row.names = c(NA, 21L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to remove any variable that repeats the same value more than x times (5 times in this example) in both levels, A and B. My desired output is

```
df2 <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 
0L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), V2 = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
6L, 4L, 5L, 2L), level = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "level"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

I have thought of `subset()` the data according to the levels, perform my previous command and join them again, but this seemed a very long way. I cannot think of a proper command to do the job. Any ideas for a shorter command that would do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Your input data are a bit confusing, and I'm not sure what you really want. Could you change your data to plain data frames, and even better displayed in a tabular way

Comment: @mb14 It doesn't seem that confusing to me.

Comment: @SimonO101 it does to me, therefore I won't answer the question, but I'm sure you would

Comment: @mb14 Copy and paste the data into your `R` session. It gives exactly what you want. This is the best way the OP can show their data. It is the exact structure of their input data. Perhaps you would be best served by reading `?structure` and/or `?dput` I guess you are not so familliar with R?

Comment: @mb14, the data I am showing shows 3 different cases, the first column should stay because it doesn't have repeating values, the third column should be removed, because it has a value that repeats more than x times in both levels. The issue here is mainly with the second column, where it contains the value "2" 11 times, but it is not repeated in the level B more than 5 times. My command would remove the second column, where I would like it to stay. I hope this makes my question more clear :)

Comment: @Error404 your question is clear to anyone with familiarity in the `R` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `table` on both columns to get a two way table and then use `apply` and see if `any` row in the resulting tables has `all` `TRUE` values (i.e. value appears more than `x` times....

```
#  Two column tables
lens <- lapply( df[ , -ncol(df) ] , function(x) table( x , df$level ) > 5 )

#  Which columns have ANY values that have more repeats in ALL levels
ind <- sapply( lens , function(x) ! any( apply( x , 1 , all ) ) )

#  Subset
df <- df[, ind ]

head( df )
  V1 V2 level
1  1  2     A
2  2  2     A
3  3  2     A
4  4  2     A
5  5  2     A
6  6  2     A
```

Comment: That's brilliant! thanks Simon! I hope I would be able to establish such commands soon :)

Comment: @Error404 no problem, glad I could help. I am sure there are some better ways to do this, but this is the one that readily sprang to my mind.